# Why does every new asp.net mvc 4 project template base on WebApi Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When I create a new ASP.NET MVC 4.0 project e.g. Single Page App or Mobile etc... they all have Controller classes inheriting from ApiController.

I do not need to expose a web service to someone else. I just want to run a public website with a private webapplication if logged in. I do not want ApiController but I want a Single Page App.

Why have they done it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebApi does not necessarily imply that you are creating a web service for someone else.  Instead, when you are developing a single page app, you would use the WebApi controllers to deal with getting/posting data via ajax.

There is nothing stopping you from using regular controllers, but the WebApi is well suited for SPA.  See any of the online tutorials where this technique is used.

Comment: "Instead, when you are developing a single page app, you would use the WebApi controllers to deal with getting/posting data via ajax." Well all my controllers get or return data with ajax without WebApi controllers. What has WebApi to do with Ajax?

Comment: @Elisa I am with you. WebApi has nothing to do with Ajax. I think the answer to your question is really that Microsoft simply wanted to promote their new thing and decided to include it by default on all new projects. That's all. Yes, WebApi is convenient for Ajax but so is a regular Controller returning Json.

Comment: What made you jump to "Whats WebApi have to do with ajax?"  WebApi isnt tied to ajax, but single page applications are.  Controllers or ApiControllers, youll be using ajax to call the actions, no?  Of course you can use JsonResults from a normal controller, but WebApis make returning JSON/xml/whatever automatic, rather than relying on ***Result

Comment: @Bort Your statement:"you would use the WebApi controllers to deal with getting/posting data via ajax." made me jump...

Comment: The idea, it seems to me at least, behind WebApi was to separate actions that deal with transferring data and actions that return html.  WebApi lets you return your objects and it serializes them to JSON or whatever the request asked for.

Comment: @Bort yes now I have really seen it and understood. No more results thats cool. But what if I want to use a my own Json serializer where can override the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create an Mvc4 Web Application using the **Internet Application** project template.  This template uses forms authentication and creates controllers that inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.  If you are using Visual Studio 2012 then this template is installed (along with a handful of others including the Api Web template).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your controllers folder -> Add -> Controller and then choose an MVC controller from the template drop down. You don't have to use an API Controller.

If you think of what a SPA is, it's essentially an HTML page that uses JavaScript to get data from a WebAPI or some other web service. Like Bort said, web API calls are very well suited for SPA.

Personally, for a single page app, before they added the SPA template in Update 1 I'd just create a static .html page and make RESTful calls into my WebAPI controllers.